# How to get rid of some long randomly named columns of a form list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, form

Not sure why I got these columns. It could be because of old versions of the form templates. But how can I delete them all together? not one by one? 
Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are they found in multiple Apps / lists / libraries?

If they are in one list, is it using content types?

If no I would just delete the columns manually. (how many do you have in total?)

Comment: In many the form lists that were upgraded from SharePoint 2007. Not in content types. Just too many of them...

Comment: Powershell would be a good way to go then so you could delete the columns in bulk and loop though the sites and lists that contain them. Here is a site I found that has some of the info you need to get started. http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/04/how-to-remove-column-from-sharepoint-list-using-powershell.html